# Define global variable using function argument in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables

I'm trying to write a function in R that drops columns from a data frame and returns the new data with a name specified as an argument of the function:

```
drop <- function(my.data,col,new.data) {
new.data <<- my.data[,-col] 
return(new.data)
}
```

So in the above example, I want a new data frame to exist after the function is called that is named whatever the user inputs as the third argument.

When I call the function the correct data frame is returned, but then if I then try to use the new data frame in the global environment I get `object not found`. I thought by using the `<<-` operator I was defining `new.data` globally.

Can someone help me understand what's going on and if there is a way to accomplish this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330468/how-can-i-define-a-global-variable-text-in-r) that seemed related, but neither quite answered my question.

Comment: You could `assign(new.data, mydata[,-col], envir = .GlobalEnv)` although I would recommend against this whole idea

Comment: It looks like your function requires more typing than explicitly doing the call directly.  What is the point?  Also assigning things using `<<-` from within a function is terrible practice.

Comment: You are trying to write a function with a side effect. R is a functional language and thus functions shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: @Dason ah good to know that <<- should'nt be used in a function - thanks. My actual function is longer than this I was just using this as an easy example. It does save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `assign()` function.

```
  assign("new.data", my.data[,-col], envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The first argument should be a string.  In this case, the resultant global variable will be named "new.data".  If `new.data` is the name itself, drop the quotes from the function call.

`<<-` does not always assign to the global environment.

In general, however, it is better to return things from a function than set global variables from inside a function.  The latter is a lot harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I'll live with slightly more typing and just use `return`.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead: I expanded to explain when to quote and when not to.

Comment: Is there a systematic way to do this for a pile of variables?

Answer (score 0):

One reason to need this is when working a great deal with the RStudio console to perform lots of text mining.  For example, if you have a large corpus and you want to break it up into sub-corpi based on themes, performing the processing as a function and returning a cleaned corpus can be much faster.  An example is below:

```
 processText <- function(inputText, corpName){
  outputName <- Corpus(VectorSource(inputText))
  outputName <- tm_map(outputName,PlainTextDocument)
  outputName <- tm_map(outputName, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  outputName <- tm_map(outputName, removePunctuation)
  outputName <- tm_map(outputName, removeNumbers)
  outputName <- tm_map(outputName, stripWhitespace)
  assign(corpName, outputName, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return(corpName)
}
```

In the case above, I enter the column from the data frame as the `inputText` and the desired output corpus as `corpName`.  This allows the simple task of the following to process a bunch of text data:

```
processText(retail$Essay,"retailCorp")
```

Then the new corpus "retailCorp" shows up in the global environment for further work such as plotting word clouds, etc.  Also, I can send lists through the function and get lots of corpi back.